# how can I get the mouse and keyboard to work simultaneously in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I've written a simple code using pygame just to test a situation where a player uses key presses and mouse motion simultaneously. However, I'm unable to move the mouse while pressing a key. The code is below:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you very much. Despite the simplicity of the question, Google couldn't find anything.

Comment: You say 'However, I'm unable to move the mouse while pressing a key'. Are you saying that while you are depressing a key the mouse will not move on the screen (it sounds like you are saying that but it seems unlikely), or are you trying to say that while you are checking if a key is pressed you are not able to detect if the mouse is moving?

Comment: Yes, the mouse cursor stops on the screen when I hold a key down. I was hoping the mouse cursor would move freely on the screen so the player could control something while holding a key down, but it just stops.

Comment: I have not seen the behaviour you are describing. I just brought up a pygame program that I wrote that uses both mouse and keyboard and the mouse moves fine when a key is pressed. I also just copied the code you have above and ran it and did not see this behaviour either. This is on Windows 10.

Comment: I've noticed the code works on my computer only when I'm pressing one of the following keys: arrow keys, Shift, Ctrl, Alt, Tab, Delete, Insert, and F1 to F12. With the other keys the problem persists and the mouse get stuck on the screen.

Comment: I'm a bit late for the party but i found i have the same problem - only when using the touchpad on my laptop... so this could potentialy have nothing to do with pygame and/or your code...

Answer (score 1):

The supplied program (at least for me) is quite capable of handling the mouse movement and detecting key-presses simultaneously.

A simple addition of logging information will confirm this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()

    keys  = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print( "up, mouse@ "+str( mouse ), end="     \r" )
    else:
        print( "not up, mouse@ "+str( mouse ), end="     \r" )

    pygame.display.update()
```

Run this script, move the mouse, periodically pressing <kbd>↑</kbd>.

I can quite easily switch between this outputting `up` and `not up`, with the mouse constantly moving.

If this is *not* the case for you, then likely it is some issue with Pygame and your operating environment.  I would re-install PyGame in this case, ensuring a modern version of both Python and PyGame.

Comment: Your code worked fine and I was actually able to move the mouse on the screen while holding K_up, also the messages printed confirmed both mouse and K_up were operating together. Although, I tried to change K_up to K_a in your code and, in this case, the problem persisted and the mouse stopped on the screen again.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop pooling events, detect mouse and key inputs there

eg.

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                      Do Something
    
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                      if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                           Do Something else
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Still, the mouse wont move on the screen while holding down K_w or any other key.